# Ansible failed while installing Mysql

Tags: ansible

Ansible failed while installing Mysql

```
fatal: [cvhnd-comm-s-alberto]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "gid": 0, "group": "root", "mode": "0755", "msg": "chown failed: failed to look up user mysql", "owner": "root", "path": "/home/mysql/.aws", "size": 4096, "state": "directory", "uid": 0}
```

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to change the ownership of `/home/mysql/.aws` to use `mysql` but when that happens, the user is not yet created. You should try changing the order of operations so that the installation of mysql with the package manager come before this operation.